# Decrypt wildfly management user password

Tags: wildfly

I have a wildfly 21 installation with a management user (added using the add-user.sh). I forgot the password and I was wondering if it's possible to decrypt the value stored in the *application-users.properties* instead of generating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The password is only stored as a hash, so you will not be able to decrypt it.
And trying to break it might not be worth the effort.

I would just use the add-user.sh script and add a new user with the same name again.
It will then ask you if you want to overwrite/update the user and you are able to supply a new password.